# Yarn install gives error on installing node-forge module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

When I am running yarn install I am getting this error:

> error https://registry.npmjs.org/node-forge/-/node-forge-0.7.5.tgz: Extracting tar content of undefined failed, the file appears to be corrupt: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache\v4\npm-node-forge-0.7.5-6c152c345ce11c52f465c2abd957e8639cd674df\node_modules\node-forge\flash\swf\SocketPool.swf'"

Answer (score 0):

Let's debug this. Try to install this module using npm and see if it works or, if it fails, what error it returns.

At [node-forge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge) we can see that this can be done by executing the following command:

```
$ npm i node-forge
```

This is an alternative that can give you a hint on how to resolve this error.

Comment: Ok. So the error is only for yarn. Let me see your package.json if you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case yarn cache clean, delete yarn.lock doesn't work

but setting npm registry works

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org.au/
```